# How to add a column to Angular material table to set the row active/inactive, while the checkbox should not affected

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

After adding a column to set status active/inactive, the checkbox is also getting selected/deselected.

I have this code:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                      [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                      [disabled]="row.excluded">


        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="toggleActive(element.id)"> {{activeStatus}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

How to add a custom column to this mat-table, so that the click for status will not have affect on the row, means the check box should not be selected or deselected?

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz demo?

Comment: Are you trying to click the `status` column and not affect the `checkbox`? we need some typescript code of the `toggleActive` method perhaps, to see what are you doing in the background